# Solve the equation $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right)^{\sqrt{1-x}} = (\sqrt{1-x})^{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}$

Tags: functions, inequality, logarithms, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

Solve in $\mathbb{R}$:
$
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right)^{\sqrt{1-x}} = (\sqrt{1-x})^{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}
$
My approach:
Let $a = \sqrt{1-x}$ and $b = \sqrt{1+x}$ so $a^2 + b^2 = 2$. The equation becomes $\left(\frac{1+ab}{2}\right)^a = a^{a+b}$, which is equivalent to $\left(\frac{1+ab}{a^2+b^2}\right)^a = a^{a+b}$. After taking the natural logarithm, we get $a \ln(1+ab) - a \ln(a^2+b^2) = a \ln(a) + b \ln(a)$. I thought of considering a function but I couldn't find it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $x = 0$ is a solution.  You may be able to show that it is the only real solution.

Comment: @DMcMor can this be proved using $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, $x = 0$ is a solution.

We claim that $x = 0$ is the only solution.

If $-1 \le x < 0$, we have
$$\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\Big)^{\sqrt{1-x}}
< 1 < (\sqrt{1-x})^{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}.$$

If $0 < x \le 1$, we have
$$\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\Big)^{\sqrt{1-x}}
\ge
\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2} > \frac{\sqrt{1 - x} + \sqrt{1 - x}}{2},$$
and
$$(\sqrt{1-x})^{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}
\le \sqrt{1 - x}.$$
Thus, $\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\Big)^{\sqrt{1-x}} > (\sqrt{1-x})^{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}$.

The claim is proved.

Answer (score 1):

I try follow yours ideas, but i first note $$1+ab = \frac{(a+b)^2}{2}$$

So we have $$(2a)In\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = (a+b)In(a)$$

Equivalent to solve $In\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{a+b}{2a}\right)In(a)$.

This is basically $In(x)=\frac{x}{y}In(y)$

Which, I don’t know to solve, but wolfram solve for $a=b=1$.
Hence $$\sqrt{1-x}=1 \\ \sqrt{1+x}=1$$

Has only $x=0$, which has the idea of the comment of @DMcMor. Sorry, this is incomplete if we don’t know solve $In(x)=\frac{y}{x}In(y)$, I read something about W lambert function.

Comment: Is $f(x)=\frac{ln(x)}{x}$ injective?

Comment: I looked at the other solution and he made a mistake

Comment: @math.enthusiast9 I am curious about your question about injective, u have an new idea?

Comment: @Antony Theo. Can we correct his solution?

Comment: I thought we could prove that the function is strictly monotonic to get x=y but I’m not sure how.

Comment: Isn’t de function strictly increasing on $(0;e)$ and strictly decreasing on (e; infinity)? So it would be injective in these intervals?

Comment: @Lsmarks Im pretty possitive  there are no mistakes but please tell me where you think i went wrong so I can clear things up and/or correct it

Comment: I think about your ideia, we have $f(x)=xIn(x)$ is monotonous for $x\geq1$ but not for $0\leq x \leq1$ which is decreasing for $0 \leq x \leq k$ and increasing for $k \leq x \leq 1$ so we have. For any $x \in [0,1]$ we have another y in same interval such that $f(x)=f(y)$ where k is the real such that In(k)=1

Comment: to solve $\log(x)=\frac{y}{x} \log(y) $ you multiply both sides by $x$ , let $f(x)=x \log(x)$ ......... can you see it?

Comment: @AntonyTheo so how do we prove x=y?

Comment: @Lsmarks I think in our problem we get $In(x)=\frac{x}{y}In(y)$

Comment: @Lsmarks keep in mind that $In(x)=\frac{x}{y}In(y)$ is the correct form

Comment: @Lsmarks we don’t need the function $xln(x)$

Comment: @Lsmarks I don’t understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @Lsmarks I'm not really sure how to do the injectivity part

Comment: @math.enthusiast9 I misconception that, $\frac{In(x)}{x}$ is not injective, and in (0,e) is increasing, and decreasing for (e,infinite) as u mentioned. So I don’t know find the x,y to equality. All my ideia is supposed in the injection :/

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a^2+b^2 = 2 \implies a^2+b^2+2ab = 2(1+ab)$. Hence
$$\left(\frac{1+ab}{2}\right)^a = a^{a+b} \implies \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{2a} = a^{a+b} \implies \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{2/(a+b)} = a^{1/a} \tag{*}$$

**Claim**: $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ is injective for $x \in [0,e]$ (Define $f(0)$ as $\lim_{x \to 0}x^{1/x} = 0$). 
**Proof**: We show it is strictly increasing in the said interval. 
$f'(x) = x^{1/x} \left(\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2}\right)$
which is non-negative in the said interval (it is zero only at two points 0 and $e$, and otherwise strictly positive). $\blacksquare$

Using the claim on $(*)$, and noting that $a,\frac{a+b}2 \in [0,e]$ (as $a,b \le \sqrt{2}<e$) we must have $\frac{a+b}2 = a$, which gives the desired answer $\boxed{x=0}$.

Comment: Can we prove that f is strictly increasing without derivatives?

Comment: I think there is a proof without derivatives for $x \in [0,1]$. I will try to extend it till $e$, but I doubt it will work as we will be be totally lost without $\ln$, which inly comes into play if we take the derivative.

Comment: I haven't really worked with derivatives so that's why I asked

Comment: Was this question supposed to be solved without calculus (like, what is the source)?

Comment: It's supposed to be solved without calculus

Comment: Does it help taking $ln$?

Comment: No, any argument that you perform by _taking_ log on both sides can be reversed by raising each step to the said power. Maybe we can prove that it is increasing on $[0,\sqrt 2]$ using precalculus.

Comment: How would we do that? I tried calculating f(x)-f(y)/x-y

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-We have an equation with reals $a,b$ of the form $$\left(\frac{1+ab}{2}\right)^a=a^{a+b}$$ If I take $a=b$ then I get $$\left(\frac{1+a^2}{2}\right)^a=(a^2)^a\Rightarrow 1+a^2=2a^2\Rightarrow a^2=1$$ so $(\sqrt{1-x})^2=(\sqrt{1+x})^2=1$ and $x=0$ and the equation is verified. Thus $x=0$ is a solution.

To prove that it is the only solution is not immediate.I leave this here as a simple comment.